# Laravel 9 - problems when clicking submit button twice

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-9

So I'm working on a Laravel project, and making a "create" form.

Let say I have a Product(id, name, price) table, with "name" being unique.

I have a "create" form, which require `name` and `price`, when the form is submitted, the backend will validate (name and price not null, name is not duplicate).

If validation success, user will be redirected to the "Product List" page with a "succeed" alert.

If validation failed, system will go back to the form with a "failed" alert contains the `Exception`.

All work well until I decide to test it with my double-click Logitech mouse, when i accidentally pressed the "Create" button twice, and all sort of weird things happen.

1. sometimes, the "succeed" alert present on the "Create" form page,
   which should only have the "failed" alert
2. sometimes, no alert was shown even though it failed to insert and
   there was no flow that alert does not pop-up
3. sometimes, the `id` of the items inserted was skip ahead (for
   example when there are 2 `product` with `id` `1` and `2`, the next
   `product` inserted should be with `id` `3`, but `4` was inserted
   instead, resulting in 3 product with id `1`, `2`, `4` in the
   database without the `3`).

   We only insert the `name` and `price` as the `id` is auto-increment, but
   somehow it is skipped

When the button was clicked multiple times, there was multiple request sent, could this be a concurrency problem? Is there any way to avoid it?

My code is below:

`ProductStoreRequest` class to validate request:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:Product,name,'. optional($this->Product)->id,
            'price' => 'required|numeric'
        ];
    }
```

this request will be handled by `ProductController`:

```
public function store(ProductStoreRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->ProductRepository->insert($request->validated());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return back()->withError($e->getMessage())->withInput();
        }

        if (!$result) {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withError(__('requests.failed'))
                ->withInput();
        }
        return redirect()
            ->route('product.index')
            ->withSuccess(__('requests.store', ['attribute' => __('validation.attributes.product')]));
    }
```

This is the `ProductRepository` class to insert new record:

```
public function insert($request): bool
    {
        $name = $request['name'];
        $price = $request['price'];

        $names = collect($this->model->all())->pluck('price', 'name')->toArray();
        
        $inputs=['name' => $name, 'price' => $price];
       
        $inputs = Arr::undot(array_diff(Arr::dot($inputs), $names));


        return $this->model->insert($inputs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me before. And what I did was to pass my form through AJAX. In AJAX you can assign a `beforeSend` function where you can disable the Submit Button once clicked. In the pure Laravel approach, I don't have an idea how to do it.

In case you need it, here's the code below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ route('form.create')", 
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', true); // this will disable button
    },
    success:function(response) {
        }
});
```